# CDH4 looking for java in a different directory

Tags: java, hadoop, cloudera

I ran `hadoop` command on a machine which had Cloudera CDH 4.3 installed, and ran into this error:

```
/workplace/cloudera/parcels/CDH-4.3.1-1.cdh4.3.1.p0.110/bin/../lib/hadoop/bin/hadoop: line 139: /opt/java/latest/bin/java: No such file or directory
/workplace/cloudera/parcels/CDH-4.3.1-1.cdh4.3.1.p0.110/bin/../lib/hadoop/bin/hadoop: line 139: exec: /opt/java/latest/bin/java: cannot execute: No such file or directory
```

then i checked the java on that machine and found it's installed but at a different location:

```
whereis java
java: /usr/bin/java /etc/java /usr/lib/java /usr/share/java /usr/share/man/man1/java.1.gz
```

How can i make CDH4 pick up the java from `/usr/bin/java`?

Comment: How have you set `JAVA_HOME`?

Answer (score 0):

Make a symbolic link /opt/java/latest/bin/java -> /usr/bin/java?